# How to call a method of the fragment from an activity and sending data to fragment at the same time in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I need to call a method of a fragment with event `onStart()` of activity. I found a lot of answers but Java I need in Kotlin. the same time the onStart event take values for sending to the fragment. I think that I can do this with ViewModel but I try set the value in the model I have the error "mismatch".

```
public class StatusStudent: ViewModel(){
    var  status = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    fun setStatus(newStatus: Int ){
        status = newStatus //Here Error "Mismatch"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** You are trying to assign an `Int` to `MutableLiveData<Int>`.

**Solution:** What you want to do instead is assigning the value held by the `MutableLiveData<Int>` wrapper using the [setter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MutableLiveData.html#setValue(T)):

```
public class StatusStudent: ViewModel() {
    val status = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    fun setStatus(newStatus: Int) {
        status.value = newStatus
    }
}
```

Note: `status` should most likely be a `val` (instead of a `var`) since you are already using a mutable wrapper and don't want to change the reference of it but the value!

Comment: Really i am so lost. :'( , I am new in android. But i'm just want take the value from notification and pass to fragment. The problem is thar i dont found info in Kotlin.